# Knex 2.5.1 Returning Multiple Arrays from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, knex.js

I'm encountering an issue after upgrading from Knex version 0.20.15 to 2.5.1. In the previous version (0.20.15), when I used knex.raw to call a stored procedure, I received two arrays for two SELECT statements within the procedure. However, with Knex version 2.5.1, I'm now getting multiple arrays for the same two SELECT statements.

I would like to know how I can configure Knex version 2.5.1 to return results in the same way as Knex version 0.20.15.

Here's an example of my code:

```
-- Stored Procedure

    CREATE PROCEDURE testMon
    AS
    BEGIN 
        SELECT TOP(2) CustName FROM Customer
        SELECT TOP(3) BraID FROM Branch
    END;

-- Version
   "knex": "^0.20.15"
   "mssql": "^6.3.1"

-- In nodejs
    const connection = await knex.client.acquireConnection();
    const result = await connection.request().execute("testMon");
    knex.client.releaseConnection(connection);
    return result.recordsets;

-- Result Value (Knex 0.20.15)
[
  [ 
    { CustName: 'BanStore' }, 
    { CustName: 'ChipCompany' } 
  ],
  [ 
    { BraID: '008' }, 
    { BraID: '002' }, 
    { BraID: '004' } 
  ]
]

-- Version
   "knex": "^2.5.1"
   "mssql": "^9.1.1"

-- In nodejs
    return knex.raw(`testMon`);

-- Result Value (Knex 2.5.1)
[   
  [ { CustName: 'BanStore' } ], 
  [ { CustName: 'ChipCompany' } ], 
  [ { BraID: '008' } ], 
  [ { BraID: '002' } ], 
  [ { BraID: '004' } ]
]
```

I'm attempting to create a suitable mapping approach for the data returned from Knex, but I believe my current method might not be optimal.